# Confusion about > selector and its usuage in css

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-selectors

I am new to css n jquery and I am using jquery tabs for menu of my
website where I wanted to add triangle to each of selected tab. I was able 
achieve triangle shape effect in the menu but I am still confused about 
selector combinator( >) I used o. To be more clear. Consider Following code 
    css :

```
 #tabs .ui-tabs-active a > .arrow-down
 {

 display: block !important;
 top:40.5px;
 margin:-15px !important;
 left:45px; 
 }    #tabs .ui-tabs-active a > .arrow-down-border    {    z-index: 100000; 
 display: block !important;    top:42px;   
 margin:-15px !important;    left:45px;    }
```

html:

```
<div id="tabs" style="border:none;" >
<ul style="background:none;border:none; width:30%; ">
<li>

<a href="#tabs-1">Games 
<div class="arrow-down"> </div>
<div class="arrow-down-border"> </div>
</a> </li>

<li><a href="#tabs-2">Activities
<div class="arrow-down"> </div>
<div class="arrow-down-border"> </div>
</a></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

It is working perfectly fine right. But I wanted to know when I use `#tabs .ui-tabs-    active li a > .arrow-down` instead of `#tabs .ui-tabs-active a > .arrow-down` , I didn't get same 
effect. What difference does inclusion of li make that I cannot get 
triangle shape. Just curious. Sorry if this question is silly...Thanks.

Comment: Based on the context of your question and the title of your question, the ">" doesn't have anything to do with the difference you're looking for. There's really no reason to bring up the greater than symbol at all as your real question does not ask about the greater than symbol at all. Clarify that better next time or you'll confuse people trying to help you.

Comment: Sure. I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, `.ui-tabs-active` is the class which will exist **on** an `li` element.  When you do:

```
#tabs .ui-tabs-active li a > .arrow-down
```

This part:

```
.ui-tabs-active li
```

is looking for an `li` element contained **within** an element with the class of `ui-tabs-active`.  This does not exist as `.ui-tabs-active`  **is** the `li`.  Instead, you could do this:

```
#tabs li.ui-tabs-active a > .arrow-down
```

In this way, `li.ui-tabs-active` is an `li` element which **has** the class `ui-tabs-active`.

Comment: I tried it with li.ui-tabs-active as you recommended , it worked like charm. Thanks a ton.